# CASE switch inner join table mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, case

So I have a table that contains edits on three other tables, and I need to switch the inner join depending on a value, ce.entity_id. Yes, I could have normalized this edits content_edits table, but this seemed a lot easier.

```
        SELECT ce.id, ce.file, ce.date_init, ce.content_type, ce.created_by_id, ce.status, ce.date_decide, u.username
                         FROM content_edits AS ce
                         INNER JOIN users AS u
                         ON ce.created_by_id=u.id
                             CASE ce.entity_type
                                WHEN ce.entity_type=0 THEN
                                  INNER JOIN m_articles AS m
                                  ON ce.entity_id=markers.id
                                WHEN 1 THEN
                                  INNER JOIN groups AS g
                                  ON ce.entity_id=groups.id
                                WHEN 3 THEN
                                  INNER JOIN e_news AS e
                                  ON ce.entity_id=events.id
                         WHERE ce.status=1
                         LIMIT 10
```

Sincere thanks for any help. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: syntactically your code is incorrect, clarify what do you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The join cannot be dependent on a `CASE`. You can either union all the three tables together in an inner query and then use them together like the query below

```
SELECT ce.id, ce.file, ce.date_init, ce.content_type, ce.created_by_id, ce.status, ce.date_decide, u.username,S.details
                         FROM content_edits AS ce
                         INNER JOIN users AS u
                         ON ce.created_by_id=u.id
                         INNER JOIN (
                           /*add details required columns*/
                           select 0 as entity_type,a.id as entity_id,a.art_details as details
                            from m_articles AS a
                            union all 
                           select 1 as entity_type,g.id as entity_id,g.grp_details as details
                            from groups AS g
                           union all 
                           select 3 as entity_type,n.id as entity_id,n.n_details as details
                            from e_news AS n
                           )S
                                  ON ce.entity_id=S.entity_id
                                  AND ce.entity_type = S.entity_type
                         LIMIT 10;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b984/1

Comment: Hey, sorry for responding so slow. Had to head out for a while. Sometimes I get to thinking I actually know something, and then I get an amazing answer to a question like this and realize how little I know. And such a kind person to go through the trouble of making a fiddle. I can't thank you enough. It works great. Any suggestions as to where I should turn if I get stuck on SQL stuff again?

Answer (score 1):

The `CASE WHEN` function can be used to conditionally filter records but not structure a recordset. Specifically, this means it can be used in the `SELECT`, `WHERE`, AND even `JOIN ON` clauses. However, it cannot depending on dynamic criteria choose which tables to join.

The very first task of the query optimizer is to read the `FROM` and `JOIN` lines then work to filter, aggregate, select, and/or order the records.

Alternatively, you can use a `UNION` query. It may be repetitious but it is more human readable and one can understand the structure of the tables. And depending on `ce_entity_id`, only one of the unionized tables will output.

```
 SELECT ce.id, ce.file, ce.date_init, ce.content_type, 
        ce.created_by_id, ce.status, ce.date_decide, u.username
 FROM content_edits AS ce
 INNER JOIN users AS u ON ce.created_by_id=u.id
 INNER JOIN m_articles AS m ON ce.entity_id=markers.id
 WHERE ce.entity_type = 0 AND ce.status=1
 LIMIT 10;

 UNION 

 SELECT ce.id, ce.file, ce.date_init, ce.content_type, 
        ce.created_by_id, ce.status, ce.date_decide, u.username
 FROM content_edits AS ce
 INNER JOIN users AS u ON ce.created_by_id=u.id
 INNER JOIN groups AS g ON ce.entity_id=groups.id
 WHERE ce.entity_type = 1 AND ce.status=1
 LIMIT 10;

 UNION 

 SELECT ce.id, ce.file, ce.date_init, ce.content_type, 
        ce.created_by_id, ce.status, ce.date_decide, u.username
 FROM content_edits AS ce
 INNER JOIN users AS u ON ce.created_by_id=u.id
 INNER JOIN e_news AS e ON ce.entity_id=events.id
 WHERE ce.entity_type = 3 AND ce.status=1
 LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Your clear denotation of Union really helped me see I could write selects and just put unions between them and it worked ~